# Structure Factor for diffraction patterns

Tags: diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

im trying to figure out myself the use of Structure Factor for Diffraction patterns.

I have the Structure Factor for a monoatomic lattice

$S(\overline G)=\sum_{i=1}^n f e^{\overline G \cdot \overline d_i}$

Where $\overline G$ is the reciprocal lattice vector and $d_i$ are the position of the atoms in the unit cell and im summing for all the atoms in the unitary cell.

I know that the simple cubic lattice has all the  diffraction maximum.

So I know that if i want to know for which miller indices $S(\overline G)$ vanishes for example, in the BCC strucutre, I can take the simple cubic and add a basis, building a BCC so i get

The basis for the simple cubic is $\overline {R_l}=a(1,1,1) $

and the basis is

$d_1=(0,0,0)$

$d_2=\frac{2\pi}{a}(1,1,1)$

So all i must do is take the Reciprocal lattice vector G for a simple cubic, which is

$\overline G=\frac{2\pi}{a}(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ and calculate the them of the sum.

Im okay with this, all i have to do if i want to know for which values $S(\overline G)$ vanishes, is do a simple cubic and add a basis (for a diamond i add a basis for the FCC and also a basis for the additional diamond atoms). But reading bibliography tells me that i can also obtain directly $S(\overline G)$, without using a simple cubic. I can get for which miller indexes the $S(\overline G)$ vanishes in the BCC, starting from a BCC.

Can anyone clarify me this?
Thanks!